How many subgames are there in this game?
Consider the following extensive form game:

How many subgames are there in this game?
Suggested Solution: There are two subgames. One after P1 plays R and P2 plays r, and then
the whole game.
My question: is there a way to judge whether it is a subgame? I find this answer could be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657539/how-to-recognize-a-proper-sub-game
But why the game here starts at $P_2$ is not a subgame? $P_2$ obviously knows where he is.

P2 knows where they are, but if P3 plays afterward, they don't.
To see if a subgame starts at a node, check whether any of the weakly later nodes are connected by an information set with a node that does not come weakly later.
